# strings.index unicode behaviour

Tags: string, go, unicode, ascii

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.Index("ééé hannah","han"))
    fmt.Println(strings.Index("eee hannah", "han"))
}
```

Expected output:

```
4
4
```

Actual output:

```
7
4
```

I suspect that this behaviour has something to do with the fact that `é` is non-ASCII character. Do you know any way how I can achieve the expected output?

Comment: Here's a naive implementation: https://play.golang.org/p/44gSAjTubJC - you'd still have issue with decomposed Unicode characters, as shown in the code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has **byte index** at 7 and 4, see comments, try [it](https://play.golang.org/p/xMWMmSnjGlc):

```
    s1 := "ééé hannah"
    s2 := "eee hannah"
    s3 := "han"
    fmt.Println([]rune(s3))
    // [104 97 110]

    fmt.Println([]rune(s1))
    // [233 233 233 32 104 97 110 110 97 104]
    fmt.Println([]byte(s1))
    // [195 169 195 169 195 169 32 104 97 110 110 97 104]
    fmt.Println(strings.Index(s1, s3))

    fmt.Println([]rune(s2))
    // [101 101 101 32 104 97 110 110 97 104]
    fmt.Println([]byte(s2))
    // [101 101 101 32 104 97 110 110 97 104]
    fmt.Println(strings.Index(s2, s3))
```

---

See: `Go/src/strings/strings.go`, it uses `IndexByte` :

```
// IndexByte returns the index of the first instance of c in s, or -1 if c is not present in s.
func IndexByte(s string, c byte) int {
    return bytealg.IndexByteString(s, c)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In that case I worked with byte arrays after this.

Answer (score 1):

So the as wasmup already stated in their answer: `strings.Index` returns the byte index. What you're expecting is the unicode index. Unicode characters like `é` actually are multi-byte encoded things, as which is why the 3 `é`'s in your input string seemingly get counted twice (yielding the index of 7 rather than the expected 4).

#### Some background

A string in golang is basically a slice of bytes. That's why `strings.Index` returns the values it does: the offset at which a match was found in bytes. Unicode deals with code points to allow for multi-byte characters, however. Rather than have a rather abstractly named type called `codepoint`, golang calls this type a `rune`. There's a lot more to say on the matter, but you can read more [here](https://blog.golang.org/strings).

With this in mind, though, we can create our own `Index` function that gives you the rune index, rather than a byte index. Let's call the function `RuneIndex`. An off-the-cuff implementation of such a function could look something like this:

```
func RuneIndex(str, sub string) int {
    // ensure valid input
    if len(str) == 0 || len(sub) == 0 {
        return -1
    }
    // convert to rune slices
    rin, rmatch := []rune(str), []rune(sub)
    // iterate over input until end of string - length of match we're trying to find
    for i := 0; i < len(rin) - len(rmatch); i++ {
        // slight optimisation: if the first runes don't match, don't bother comparing full substrings
        if rin[i] != rmatch[0] {
            continue
        }
        // compare substrings directly, if they match, we're done
        if string(rin[i:i+len(rmatch)]) == sub {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

It's basically just comparing the substring to a sub-slice of the string we're trying to search in. By converting the rune sub-slice to a string, we can just use the `==` operator, and if a match is found, we return `i`, which is the rune index (instead of byte index). I've added some checks to make sure the arguments aren't empty, and the function returns -1 if no index was found, similarly to the standard library function.

The implementation is pretty simplistic, and not highly optimised, but seeing as I consider this rather a niche thing to want to do, optimising this type of function is something I'd classify as micro-optimisation anyway.